# Return to previous update in Java

Tags: java

I have just installed java 8 update 101 in windows 10 PC and I have a problem..

I am using netbeans IDE and  I develop a web application with a servlet and some JSPs.. In a page where I use [bootstrap table](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table), it reloads continuously the page.

In other PC, where it has update 91 , this reloading doesn't happen..

Do you know how can I go back to java update 91?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have multiple versions of JDK on your computer. Then you just have to change your `JAVA_HOME` in system properties.

Also on Oracle website, you can download older versions of JDK.

**JDK 8u91 :** http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase8-2177648.html#jdk-8u91-oth-JPR

Answer (score 1):

You can download the old version from Oracle's archive.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/archive-139210.html

You can have multiple versions of java running simultaneously and in your IDE, you can specify which java version you want to use for you JVM or you can also remove current version completely and re-install the old version.